# insert into sql oracle statemenet

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

i have created a new column (exe. columnB) in my oracle table1, which i want to fill with values i get from the query:

```
select substr(acc_no, 10) from table1)
```

all the values i get from the query above i want to be inserted in columnB of table1.

Any help, how can i achive this? Thank you in advance

Comment: RAther than store the same data twice, follow @Gordon Linoff and create a virtual column.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `update`:

```
update table1
    set columnB = substr(acc_no, 10);
```

You don't actually need to store the column.  You can add it to the table as a *virtual column*:

```
alter table1 add columnB varchar2(255)
    generated always as (substr(acc_no, 10)) virtual;
```